# What are the minimum number of documents required for a project to adhere to PRINCE2

Tags: prince2

I've been developing a website for my organisations - its taken around 3 months so far, and I'm now gearing up for the next stage which will probably involve more people and complexity. Around 4 or 5 months worth of effort.

I've also just completed a PRINCE2 course (which I'm trying to bring into the organisation), and I'd like to apply the framework to the project.

Given my project is small, low risk, and has already started. What are the number of management artifacts I need to produce, ensuring that I cover all principals and themes.

I believe I need:

- the Project Initiation document (including a small business case,
  project plan, and the strategies)
- risk and quality registers and
- lessons and issues logs

At this point, I can't see the value of the Project Brief or Benefits Review Plan.

Are there are other documents I need to create to ensure I've following the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all of the documents are covered in the PID, but I think you have two main gaps:

- **A lack of project product description and work packages.** If you lack a PPD and work package structure you will make it more difficult for you to adhere to the principle of "Focus on Products".
- **Nothing around reporting.** This is where you get most of the overhead for your project, and you'll need this to adhere to the principles of "Manage by Exception" and "Manage by Stages".

Beyond that, to better tailor you project you should be asking "What level of detail is required in the documents produced?" rather than asking about number.  For example, a simple project could cover benefits realization within the business case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the project and your organization I believe. I would say that you should consider having a communication mgmt. strategy in place to know who to and how to communicate (stakeholders, end-users, mgmt.). This to avoid confusion and to make sure that people are informed about what is going on.

A clear setup with roles and responsibilities is also very nice to have. Who can you discuss matters with, who have have the mandate to make decisions, who to escalate issues to, etc.

Remember that, even though small right now, these documents might be your best friends in the future :)